# Display a column multiple times in SQL Server query

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I need some help with a sql query.

I've two tables `USERS` and `ENDPOINT`. For each user there are 3 rows defined in `ENDPOINT` table e.g.

```
USER   ENDPOINT      ENDPOINTTYPE
123    123456        HomePhone
123    456789        CellPhone
123    A@gmail.com   Email
```

I want to display this data in a single row e.g.

```
USER   HomePhone   CellPhone   Email
```

Can you please tell me a way to achieve this?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Any link to previous posts please? I tried to search but did not find a matching post.

Comment: You could also consider doing this pivoting at the presentation tier instead of forcing SQL Server to do it.

Comment: I answered this question earlier today if I am not mistaken

Answer (score 4):

This type of data transformation is known as *pivot*. SQL Server has a pivot function starting with SQL Server 2005.

Prior to SQL Server 2005, this could be done using an aggregate function with a `CASE` expression:

```
select [user],
  max(case when ENDPOINTTYPE = 'HomePhone' then EndPoint end) HomePhone,
  max(case when ENDPOINTTYPE = 'CellPhone' then EndPoint end) CellPhone,
  max(case when ENDPOINTTYPE = 'Email' then EndPoint end) Email
from yourtable
group by [user];
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/53939/4).

If you are using SQL Server 2005+, then the pivot query would look like:

```
select *
from
(
  select [user], endpoint, endpointtype
  from yourtable
) src
pivot
(
  max(endpoint)
  for endpointtype in (HomePhone, CellPhone, Email)
) piv
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ffc97/1)

The above queries work great if you know the values ahead of time. If you don't then you will want to use dynamic sql:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(ENDPOINTTYPE) 
                    from yourtable
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT [USER],' + @cols + ' from 
             (
                select [USER], [ENDPOINT], [ENDPOINTTYPE]
                from yourtable
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                max(ENDPOINT)
                for ENDPOINTTYPE in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ffc97/2)

All queries return the same result:

```
| USER | HOMEPHONE | CELLPHONE |       EMAIL |
----------------------------------------------
|  123 |    123456 |    456789 | A@gmail.com |
```

Comment: Quite welcome. I'd rather handle the edit than write all these $^#&@ pivot queries. :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. Didn't know about sql fiddle. This is a neat tool.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT 
    U.[User], 
    EP1.EndPoint as 'HomeEndpoint', EP1.Endpotintype as 'HomeEndpointType', 
    EP2.EndPoint as 'CellEndpoint', EP2.Endpotintype as 'CellEndpointType', 
    EP3.EndPoint as 'EmailEndpoint', EP3.Endpotintype as 'EmailEndpointType'
FROM Users U
    LEFT JOIN EndPoint EP1 ON U.[User] = EP1.[User] AND EP1.EndPointType = 'HomePhone'
    LEFT JOIN EndPoint EP2 ON U.[User] = EP2.[User] AND EP2.EndPointType = 'CellPhone'
    LEFT JOIN EndPoint EP3 ON U.[User] = EP3.[User] AND EP3.EndPointType = 'Email'
```

Or to return just those 4 columns:

```
SELECT 
    U.[User], 
    EP1.EndPoint as 'Home Phone', 
    EP2.EndPoint as 'Cell Phone', 
    EP3.EndPoint as 'Email'
FROM Users U
    LEFT JOIN EndPoint EP1 ON U.[User] = EP1.[User] AND EP1.EndPointType = 'HomePhone'
    LEFT JOIN EndPoint EP2 ON U.[User] = EP2.[User] AND EP2.EndPointType = 'CellPhone'
    LEFT JOIN EndPoint EP3 ON U.[User] = EP3.[User] AND EP3.EndPointType = 'Email'
```

Here is the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9d812/3) -- Note, I changed column User to UserId since it's a reserved word (or you could have used brackets).

Comment: Thanks for your help! This is what I needed.

How do I filter the null records? I tried using EP1.EndPoint IS NOT NULL but this didn't work..

Sorry I'm a complete newbie to sql world :(

Comment: Well, what do you want to show if Home Phone is NULL but cell phone has a value?